# Check if all select options are disabled except for one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select

how can i check if all select options are disabled except for the one with the value="0"?

Here is my code:

```
<select name="my-select" id="my-select">
    <option value="0">apple</option>
    <option value="1" disabled>orage</option>
    <option value="2" disabled>pear</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>banana</option>
</select>
```

What I was thinking was:

```
if(#my-select options disabled except for option value="0") {
    console.log(option value="0" is the only one that is enabled);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st**: You need to check for all `enabled` options by using `$('#my-select option:not(:disabled)')`

**2nd**: check How many of it is enabled using `.length`

**3rd**: check if its `value` attribute is 0

```js
var enabled = $('#my-select option:not(:disabled)');
if(enabled.length === 1 && enabled.attr('value') == "0") {
    console.log('option value="0" is the only one that is enabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my-select" id="my-select">
    <option value="0">apple</option>
    <option value="1" disabled>orage</option>
    <option value="2" disabled>pear</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you are a genius. thanks! also, just asking: is it possible to do this with vanilla javascript?

Answer (score 0):

> you can use `javascript` or `jQuery`.I use of jQuery, Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var counter = 0;
   $('#my-select option:enabled:not([value=0])').each(function(){
       counter++;
   })
   if(counter < 1)
       alert('option value="0" is the only one that is enabled');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my-select" id="my-select">
    <option value="0">apple</option>
    <option value="1" disabled>orage</option>
    <option value="2" disabled>pear</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Invalid syntax?